# Increasing the distance between top and category icon

Tags: css, wordpress

My css skills are unfortunately limited. Therefore I want to ask you if there is anybody who can help me with the following issue...?

I want to increase the distance between the top and the icon/line of "category" (above the headline of my posts) at each post on my front page, in the same style as it is on single post page. You know what I mean? Can anybody tell me which code I have to change? (that's the page: [www.veda-vit.de](http://www.veda-vit.de))

Thank you so much!

Greetings,
pradhana

Comment: Please add some code or a screenshot of the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can modify a file http://www.veda-vit.de/wp-content/themes/fluida/style.css

find a line 1510 over there and modify it:

```
    #content-masonry article.hentry .article-inner {
    padding: 1em 2em 2em;
}
```

just remove `1em` here

Comment: So you can not do. It is a violation of encapsulation. We need to use the override styles.

Comment: @Alex, do you think it's a good practice to define one selector at two different places? And that template uses `em`-s but not `px`-s. At my viewport code inspector showed padding 26px, not 22px, because we have different viewoprts. So the best way I think is just to add the line `padding-top: 2em;` below at the very place.

Comment: You could, but I do not argue, but an update template changes will be lost, so you need to rewrite styles and of course in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

The style.css file in the end add:

```
#content-masonry article.hentry .article-inner {
    padding-top: 22px; // enter your desired value
}
```

the path to the file: /wp-content/themes/fluida/style.css